# Error in wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF plugin in Wordpress to allow a client to upload images that will be used to as full screen background images on the homepage. I have fields that correspond to the days of the week and I'd like to query the database to get the current day of the week, then display the corresponding image.  I'm new to php and haven't been able to find out what I'm doing wrong. Grateful for any suggestions.

```
function my_custom_background ($today) { 

$today = date('l');

if ($today == 'Saturday') 
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('saturday'); ?>);}</style><?php;

if ($today == 'Sunday')
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('sunday'); ?>);}</style><?php;

if ($today == 'Monday')
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('monday'); ?>);}</style><?php;

if ($today == 'Tuesday')   
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('tuesday'); ?>);}</style><?php;

if ($today == 'Wednesday')
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('wednesday'); ?>);}</style><?php;

if ($today == 'Thursday') 
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('thursday'); ?>);}</style><?php;

if ($today == 'Friday') 
echo [] ?> <style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('friday'); ?>);}</style><?php;
}

add_action('wp', 'my_custom_background');
```

Comment: What you have set for return value in acf While creating the file upload field from acf for example id,url

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you encounter an error, it's important to add the error details to the question to help others understand the problem. Please add the error message and stack trace if available.

Comment: Akshay the return value in acf is url

Comment: Thanks Cy. I'm no longer getting an error message. The background image always takes whichever option is at the end of the function. For example if I were to move 'Friday' to the top the background image would take 'Thursday'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what are you trying to accomplish with this syntax?

```
echo [] ?> .... <?php;
```

You don't need the echo if you're going out of php mode for the styles, and echoing an empty array doesn't make any sense to me. I assume there has been some array modification going on originally which has been partly removed. You don't need that.

Since your fields are named fittingly, you can simplify your code:

```
function my_custom_background () { 
    $today = date('l');
    ?><style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url(<?php echo get_field(strtolower($today)); ?>);}</style><?php
}
```

You shouldn't do this with the [wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) action hook, though, that's much too early in the request life cycle. [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) is more appropriate, so add

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_background');
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure that it's actually this code that's creating the problem and not some forgotten hardcoded test in the template for example. Open the HTML source of the webpage and look for the output. See if it changes if you change output in the function.